# Better/cleaner way of writing this if clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

The following is a code from my `UsersController` action. I have a `current_user` object from a session, and I'd like to use the current user's ID if none is passed into the action.

```
def show
  id = params[:id]
  id = current_user.id if id.blank?
  @user = User.find(id)
end
```

I'm doing this so that, eventually, I can have administrators who can edit other users' info. That is why I just don't use `@user = User.find(current_user.id)`.

Thoughts/suggestions? I could probably also do a ternary operator, something like

```
params[:id].present? ? id = params[:id] : id = current_user.id
```

but I'm thinking there is probably an even better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer this way

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id] || current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: I like this as well... never really thought of just using OR, so simple.

Comment: to match exactly the original code: `@user = User.find(params[:id].presence || current_user.id)`

Comment: and you can drop the "personally", it's the only reasonable way to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

I followe this tutorial: [Tony Amoyal website](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)

Comment: I am eventually going to switch to a gem like this, but i am teaching myself authorization, so i'd like to build it myself first so i understand what is going on.